# Unable to connect to Postgresql via login/password from my web app

Tags: postgresql

On a server I'm able to connect to Postgresql via the terminal:

```
$ psql -U me123 -d my_db
psql (9.4.7)
Type "help" for help.

my_db=# \q
```

Note that it didn't ask me for the password for some reason even when I provided `-p`.

Here's my config:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf 

local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

And I believe because of that, I'm unable to connect to it from my web app on the same server via login and password and the error is `(invalid_password): password authentication failed for user "me123"` but the password is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

to allow external acces to your server.